# Random points with QGIS

Tags: qgis

When using the random points tool in QGIS, how does the process treat fractional data?  Say for example, the data point I have for a particular polygon is 4.7, does QGIS put 4 or 5 points in the polygon?  Ultimately, I am wondering whether it rounds or truncates the data.

Comment: That should be quite easy to test it by yourself ... no ?

Comment: Yes, unless the algorithm uses special rounding rules to avoid bias towards rounding up at 5, or something similar I might not catch with a quick check.  That is why I thought I would ask if someone knew.

Answer (score 5):

There is no magic. Points are added as long as the counter is bellow the supplied point count, see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/RandomPointsLayer.py

```
    while nIterations < maxIterations and nPoints < pointCount:
        rx = bbox.xMinimum() + bbox.width() * random.random()
        ry = bbox.yMinimum() + bbox.height() * random.random()

        pnt = QgsPointXY(rx, ry)
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(pnt)
        ids = idxLayer.intersects(geom.buffer(5, 5).boundingBox())
        if len(ids) > 0 and \
                vector.checkMinDistance(pnt, index, minDistance, points):
            request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(ids).setSubsetOfAttributes([])
            for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
                tmpGeom = f.geometry()
                if geom.within(tmpGeom):
                    f = QgsFeature(nPoints)
                    f.initAttributes(1)
                    f.setFields(fields)
                    f.setAttribute('id', nPoints)
                    f.setGeometry(geom)
                    writer.addFeature(f)
                    index.insertFeature(f)
                    points[nPoints] = pnt
                    nPoints += 1
                    feedback.setProgress(int(nPoints * total))
        nIterations += 1
```